# iPad Navigation Bar custom height

Tags: ios, ipad, height, uinavigationbar

I'm creating an app for people with visual impairment, so I need to have larger controls on the screen. Is there a way to have a taller Navigation Bar with bigger navigation buttons?

I've seen this question asked a few times with no definitive answer. Apple's [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW41) states "Don’t specify the height of a navigation bar programmatically," so I assume it is not supported nor recommended. Any other suggestions, besides designing it from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

sometimes I need to glitch the navigation bar.

I am hidding the bar and  I am using a component which looks like the native bar, that can have a custom height!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure how to go about this, but I would suggest subclassing the UINavigationBar. Please look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133257/iphone-how-set-uinavigationbar-height) to get some ideas.

It's for iPhone, but it should also work for iPad.