# Setting the height of the UINavigationBar

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have set a `UINavigationBar` background image to an image with a height of `68px` as opposed to the default `44px`. Now the image is shown fine, but the content in the `UINavigationController` is overlapped in the first `(68-44)px = 12px` by the header image.

How do I fix this? I have tried setting the `frame` of the `UINavigationBar` without luck.

Thanks, Caspar.

This is my code (AppDelegate.m):

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.frontTableViewController];
UINavigationBar *navBar = navigationController.navigationBar;
[navBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"header"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
```

[image: Image showing the problem]

Comment: a screenshot would help a lot to understand your problem

Comment: please also write the code you used to set the image for the UINavigation bar

Comment: @Bonnie there you go!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try setting the image for the navigationbar this way

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myNavBarImage.png"]];
```

or have a look at this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133257/iphone-how-set-uinavigationbar-height)

Comment: This only sets the title image of that particular `navigationItem` - I want the navigation bar to be a static image (with a greater height than 44px) while still having the UINavigationBar functionality

Comment: try the link in the answer

Comment: I found the solution in that link. The solution was to redefine `sizeThatFits` to the kind in the link.